# binding component objects to form elements

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have created model-driven form in angular2, I created objects with the same name directives in html template but somehow there is error thrown as pic below:

[image]

postmessage.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl,FormGroup,FormBuilder,Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'post-message',
    templateUrl: '../../templates/postmessage.component.html'
})
export class PostComponent {
    form = new FormGroup({
        username:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
        email:new FormControl('',Validators.required)
    })
    signup(){
        console.log(this.form.value);
    }
 }
```

postmessage.component.html:

```
<form class="from-horizontal" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="signup()">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="username" class="control-label col-md-2">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="username"  class="form-control" formControlName="username">
            <div class="alert alert-danger"
            *ngIf="!form.controls['username'].valid"
            >
                User name is required.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="control-label col-md-2">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"
        *ngIf="!from.controls['email'].valid"
        ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

how can fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
form = new FormControl({
```

should be

```
form = new FormGroup({
```

Comment: Yes I understood your point but still have trouble, I edited post

Comment: what does this error mean? what id does try me to tell ?

Comment: That `from` is `undefined` but `form` would work ;-) (the 2nd `*ngIf="!from.controls['email'].valid"`) https://plnkr.co/edit/IaZ3iJLWSdbi2Aar4UQc?p=preview

Comment: these are my last messages I gonna shoot myself :) thanks you bro u helped me for my previous post(Ty4HelpDude) really appreciated for your help I follow you in google also..

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad to hear you could make it work.